# Link to uploaded file in index view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made a code, for user to upload a file to the content folder in MVC4.

Same time information regards the file, is updated in the DB.

So the db and file is located 2 different Places.

How can I make a code in my index view, so users can klik on the link, and the uploaded file (pdf) will open ?

I need a link for each row in the database, connecting the the correct file in the folder "content"

Can you help me getting started ?

```
 Index


@model IEnumerable<CFire2.Models.DAT_SupplierCon>


@{
ViewBag.Title = "SupplyCon";
}

<h2>SupplyContract</h2>

p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Supplier)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pdf)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplier)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pdf)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("EditFile", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("EditDetails", "EditDetails", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What does `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pdf)` returns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your razor template

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/" + item.Pdf)
```

Not sure if Pdf is the filename, you need to use the property on your model that represents the name of the file.

Comment: Hi John, sorry I'am new here, and didn't see the rule, will not do that again

Comment: Hi Ofiris     `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pdf`     return the name of the uploaded file, not a link